# Timing of steps for Yodlee synchronized data extract

Tags: yodlee

This questions is in reference to [Yodlee data extract procedures](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Extract_Procedures).

The example and diagram towards the bottom of the page depicts a call to `getRefreshedUserItems` every minute. I'm assuming this example passes input parameters (`refreshDataFilter.startDate` and `refreshDataFilter.endDate`) which span one minute of time. In the diagram, 40 items are refreshed before `getRefreshedUserItems` is called again the next minute.

Is it necessary that all items are successfully retrieved on behalf of consumers before the next call to `getRefreshedUserItems`? I'm imagining a scenario where there may be too many items to retrieve in a given minute. Can the retrieval of items be queued and processed while the refresh continues to loop every minute?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question:

> Is it necessary that all items are successfully retrieved on behalf of consumers before the next call to getRefreshedUserItems?

No, it is not necessary that all the items were refreshed successfully. In case of failure item, where user action is required for e.g., like Password expired etc you can update those items in your data base and ask user to perform required action. In case of any other error, Yodlee re-schedule's the refresh for that item.

> Can the retrieval of items be queued and processed while the refresh
>   continues to loop every minute?
>   As, number of items should not be huge this is why Yodlee recommend to call this API every minute and get those items and may be queued and processed while continuing the loop to retrieve next set of items.